# #value error with excel distance calculation by using Google Maps API key

Tags: excel, vba, google-api

I'm trying to develop a function in excel that returns the traveltime between two locations. I used this code i found online, yet always get a #value error. When I plug in the strUrl in my browser with my apikey the request works.

Help is very much appreciated.

```
' Returns the number of seconds it would take to get from one place to another
Function TRAVELTIME(origin, destination, apikey)

    Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=" & origin & "&destinations=" & destination & "&key=" & apikey

    Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With httpReq
         .Open "GET", strUrl, False
         .Send
    End With

    Dim response As String
    response = httpReq.ResponseText

    Dim parsed As Dictionary
    Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
    Dim seconds As Integer

    Dim leg As Dictionary

    For Each leg In parsed("routes")(1)("legs")
        seconds = seconds + leg("duration")("value")
    Next leg

    TRAVELTIME = seconds

End Function
```

Comment: Go through your code step by step using F8 and check your variable values to find out where it goes wrong. Make sure you add the value of `response` to your original question (otherwise it is almost impossible to see what is happening there). Also include how you call this function (make sure you don't provide your apikey). Do you use a formula? If so which one? Do you use a procedure/sub? If so which one?

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
Looks like 'response' might be the issue. As with debugger shows for the expression 'response' a value of 'out of context'. Any ideas what to do to fix this?

The code example i got from here (looks the same to me) https://syntaxbytetutorials.com/excel-function-to-calculate-distance-using-google-maps-api-with-vba/

I call this function by using a formula: =TRAVELTIME(origin, destination, apikey) .. and i put origin, destination and the api key in a cell and reference to it

Comment: What do you get in the immediate window if you put a `Debug.Print response` right after the line `response = httpReq.ResponseText` and re-enter the formula to trigger the function to run?

Comment: When you write *the request works*, what do you mean?  That you get a result?  Or that you get a result with the same JSON structure that your code is expecting?  The JSON I see is quite different from what your code is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON structure is different than what your code is expecting.  (*Examine the Google documentation for the distance-matrix api to determine that.*)

You need something like:

```
    Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
    Dim seconds As Integer

    Dim leg As Dictionary

    For Each leg In parsed("rows")(1)("elements")
        seconds = seconds + leg("duration")("value")
    Next leg

    TRAVELTIME = seconds
```

**Note:**  You have declared `seconds as Integer`.  If you examine the VBA data types, you will note that `Integer` has a maximum value of 32,767 which is a bit more than nine (9) hours.  If the sum of your durations might be longer than this, and you do not wish to have an Overflow error, suggest you declare seconds as `Long` or `Double`.